# How to give all `grid-template-rows` same height dynamically?

Tags: css, frontend, grid, web-frontend

This is `grid-template-rows`. As you can see last rows has more height. I wanna make all of the row's height same whenever a row get more height than other's.
This must be with `display: grid;` property.[image: grid-template-rows]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `grid-auto-rows` to 1fr as the example below:

More info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows) and [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/grid-auto-rows/)

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; /* make all rows the same height */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E<br>E<br>E</div>
</div>
```