# Equal height of <li> entries in display:grid table arrangement

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```css
h3 {
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
p {
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#main_table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 8fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}
#img1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#img2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#num1 {
  background-color: beige;
}
#text1 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_table">
  <div id="img1">
    <ul>
      <li> image 1 </li>
      <li> image 2 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="img2">
    <ul>
      <li> image on first row </li>
      <li> second row </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="num1">
    <ul>
      <li> 24 </li>
      <li> a long entry </li>
      <ul>
  </div>
  <div id="text1">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the rows of the li are not of equal length.
Solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44488357/equal-height-rows-in-css-grid-layout) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75260176/how-to-give-all-grid-template-rows-same-height-dynamically) say to use `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;`, however as you can see in the above code this property is set and yet the rows are not of equal size.

[image]

Comment: You want them to have the same width or same height? Another question: the 4 on the same row or each one on a row? Thanks you

Comment: Same height, the width seems to be already set correctly by grid-template-columns. And I am fine with both same height for all rows, or just same height for any individual row.

Comment: The li elements are great grand children of the element that has display grid so are as it stands not affected by it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```css
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
```

And forget about the `grid-auto-rows` property

### Code:

```css
h3 {
  font-family: Tahoma;
}
p {
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #888888;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#main_table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
#img1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#img2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
#num1 {
  background-color: beige;
}
#text1 {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_table">
  <div id="img1">
    <ul>
      <li> image 1 </li>
      <li> image 2 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="img2">
    <ul>
      <li> image on first row </li>
      <li> second row </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="num1">
    <ul>
      <li> 24 </li>
      <li> a long entry </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="text1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This adjusts the column size, not the row size. As you can see, the row heights in the green div are different from those in the blue div.